# Checking a Html Elements Class Attributes value contains "String"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two user controls that need to add a class atribute to the body tag of my page, however they currently over write one another if I just use

```
Body.Attributes.Add("class","value")
```

So I need to check if the class attribute exsists and if it already contains the value Im going to add.

```
If Not Body.Attributes("class").Contains("value") Then
  Body.Attributes.add("class", Body.Attributes("class") + " " + "value")
End If
```

Thanks for you time, any help gratefully received.

EDIT:

The contain constraint doesnt return the expected value, resulting the the class not been concatinated, 
Example:
add class "dog" then I a different instance of the same control tries to add "dog" but the contains("dog") returns false

Comment: does your code not work? What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more coding I tried using Indexof() the value I was searching for. This allowed me to know if the class attribute contained the value already.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, but really it would be nice if you placed the actual code solution here.